# Java, storing Timezone object

Tags: java, timezone

I need to store a hashmap, key is a String, val is standard Java TimeZone. 
Between (1) storing the Id String of TimeZone and (2) storing the object itself, which way saves more memory. Intuitively I think 1, but a friend told me TimeZone is a factory class, so (2) is more efficient. Your opinion? tks

1:

```
gmtToIanaMap.put("GMT+10:00", "Australia/Sydney");
```

2:

```
gmtToIanaMap.put("GMT+10:00", TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney"));
```

Comment: No need to use a map since `TimeZone` already has this info. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that memory is an issue for you? If not, use whichever approach gives the most readable code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza For your curiosity: I receive event from Google calendar which just has offset +10 in it, so the timezone is GMT+10, but what the user means is Australia/Sydney. When Day light saving time comes, Australia/Sydney has offset +11, so the logic is broken. That's why I want to map +10 to Australia/Sydney immediately now.
Back to my question: what do you think.

Comment: @JonSkeet we are storing all data on RAM, where only a byte matters.

Comment: So your problem is about offset per date operations on some business rules?

Comment: Sounds like premature micro-optimization to me. If you're really *that* bothered about every single byte, why waste so much space storing string references? Use byte arrays instead. You'd save tens of bytes! Seriously, are you in a very tightly constrained situation? Have you actually done any profiling to prove this is significant?

Comment: Oh, and btw, mapping an offset to a time zone cannot be done unambiguously. The same offset can occur in many different time zones (with different rules about DST transitions).

Comment: Tks for comments and suggestion on byte array, good idea. Any direct answer to my original question?

Answer (score 0):

Once loaded, each timezone info will be cached (in sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile) so it does not really matter. If after accessing the  the value, you need the TimeZone object anyway, I would store the TimeZone object.

That said, and as mentioned in the comments, I'm not sure that you should worry too much about that. From what I understand, you will have something like 24+  (lets say 50 to cover x + 30 minutes types of offsets) entries in there. The timezone info are stored on disk under jre/lib/zi. Most of those are under 1k in size. The objects in memory wont be much bigger, so we are talking about 50k. Unless you are really tight on memory, this is pretty much irrelevant.

Finally, all of that is really dependant on one jre implementation and I'm not sure you want to base your design on that.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

> Your opinion? tks

What you asking for, a **mapping of offset to zone, makes no sense**. A time zone uses different offsets at different points in time -- that is the definition of a time zone!

Plus: No need for a mapping. Just ask for offset per zone.

```
ZoneId                       // Represent a time zone.
.of( "Australia/Sydney" )    // Get a time zone by its proper name `Continent/Region`. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-codes such as `CST`. 
.getRules()                  // Get the past, present, and changes to the offset used by the people of this region (this time zone).
.getOffset(                  // Get the offset in use at a particular moment in this time zone.
    Instant.now()            // Capture the current moment.
)                            // Returns a `ZoneOffset` object.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xyV7T1).

> +11:00

Whoops! At this moment, `Australia/Sydney` is eleven hours ahead of UTC rather than the ten hours you expected.

## Mapping offset-to-zone is not logical

Offsets vary by date in any time zone. While the time zone `Australia/Sydney` may be ten hours ahead on one date, it may not be ten hours on another date. Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for frequently changing the offset-from-UTC used in their jurisdiction. Sometimes they change it twice a year, when observing [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Sometimes they change it for diplomatic, political, or military reasons. So a map of offset to zone without the context of a date makes no sense.

You can get the offset in used at any moment for a particular time zone using [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) and `ZoneRules` to produce a `ZoneOffset`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" ) ;
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( Instant.now() ) ;  // Get the offset currently in use at this moment.
```

Understand that an offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

## `Map < ZoneOffset, Set < ZoneId > >`

At any given moment, any number of time zones may coincidentally have the same offset (the same number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind the prime meridian).

So it might make sense to create a map where, at a particular moment, for each possible `ZoneOffset` we collect a set of the time zones (`ZoneId`) using that offset. This would be a set where the key is a `ZoneOffset` and the value would be a `Set` of `ZoneId` objects.

This is known as a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), where a key maps to a collection of values rather than a single value. In modern Java we can get the effect of a multimap by using lambda syntax with [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)).

```
Map < ZoneOffset, Set < ZoneId > > multimap = new TreeMap <>(); // Use `TreeMap` to keep the keys (the offsets) in ascending order.

Instant instant = Instant.now();
Set < String > zoneNames = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
for ( String zoneName : zoneNames )
{
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( zoneName );
    ZoneOffset offset = zoneId.getRules().getOffset( instant );
    multimap.computeIfAbsent( offset , ( ZoneOffset key ) -> new HashSet <>() ).add( zoneId );  // Or change `HashSet` to `TreeSet` to keep the `ZoneId` objects in sorted order.
}
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "multimap.toString() of the offset in use by various time zones at: " + instant );
System.out.println( "multimap = " + multimap );
```

When run.

> multimap.toString() of the offset in use by various time zones at: 2020-01-28T00:07:36.146290Z
>
> multimap = {+14:00=[Pacific/Apia, Pacific/Kiritimati, Etc/GMT-14], +13:45=[Pacific/Chatham, NZ-CHAT], +13:00=[Antarctica/McMurdo, Pacific/Tongatapu, Pacific/Enderbury, Pacific/Fakaofo, NZ, Antarctica/South_Pole, Pacific/Auckland, Etc/GMT-13], +12:00=[Asia/Anadyr, Pacific/Wake, Pacific/Majuro, Pacific/Funafuti, Pacific/Nauru, Etc/GMT-12, Pacific/Fiji, Pacific/Tarawa, Asia/Kamchatka, Kwajalein, Pacific/Wallis, Pacific/Kwajalein], +11:00=[Australia/Sydney, Pacific/Efate, Australia/LHI, Asia/Magadan, Pacific/Norfolk, Antarctica/Macquarie, Australia/Lord_Howe, Australia/Victoria, Etc/GMT-11, Pacific/Bougainville, Australia/Tasmania, Asia/Srednekolymsk, Australia/Currie, Pacific/Pohnpei, Australia/Melbourne, Pacific/Noumea, Australia/Hobart, Pacific/Ponape, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Australia/ACT, Australia/Canberra, Australia/NSW, Pacific/Kosrae, Asia/Sakhalin], +10:30=[Australia/Adelaide, Australia/South, Australia/Broken_Hill, Australia/Yancowinna], +10:00=[Pacific/Port_Moresby, Asia/Vladivostok, Pacific/Saipan, Asia/Ust-Nera, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Etc/GMT-10, Pacific/Truk, Australia/Lindeman, Pacific/Chuuk, Australia/Brisbane, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Yap, Australia/Queensland], +09:30=[Australia/North, Australia/Darwin], +09:00=[Asia/Pyongyang, Asia/Yakutsk, Asia/Tokyo, Asia/Jayapura, Asia/Dili, Japan, Asia/Khandyga, Pacific/Palau, Etc/GMT-9, Asia/Chita, ROK, Asia/Seoul], +08:45=[Australia/Eucla], +08:00=[PRC, Singapore, Hongkong, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Hong_Kong, Asia/Ulan_Bator, Asia/Manila, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Irkutsk, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Kuching, Asia/Chongqing, Australia/Perth, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Macao, Asia/Shanghai, Antarctica/Casey, Asia/Brunei, Asia/Macau, Asia/Choibalsan, Australia/West, Asia/Singapore, Etc/GMT-8, Asia/Makassar], +07:00=[Asia/Vientiane, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Asia/Tomsk, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Asia/Jakarta, Asia/Hovd, Asia/Barnaul, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Asia/Pontianak, Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Novosibirsk, Asia/Novokuznetsk, Indian/Christmas, Etc/GMT-7, Antarctica/Davis], +06:30=[Asia/Yangon, Indian/Cocos, Asia/Rangoon], +06:00=[Asia/Dacca, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Qostanay, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Dhaka, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Kashgar, Asia/Urumqi, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Bishkek, Asia/Thimphu, Etc/GMT-6], +05:45=[Asia/Katmandu, Asia/Kathmandu], +05:30=[Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Kolkata, Asia/Colombo], +05:00=[Asia/Aqtobe, Asia/Samarkand, Indian/Kerguelen, Asia/Oral, Asia/Ashgabat, Asia/Dushanbe, Asia/Aqtau, Asia/Ashkhabad, Asia/Tashkent, Antarctica/Mawson, Asia/Karachi, Etc/GMT-5, Asia/Yekaterinburg, Asia/Atyrau, Indian/Maldives, Asia/Qyzylorda], +04:30=[Asia/Kabul], +04:00=[Indian/Mahe, Indian/Mauritius, Indian/Reunion, Europe/Astrakhan, Asia/Yerevan, Europe/Ulyanovsk, Asia/Dubai, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Tbilisi, Europe/Saratov, Europe/Samara, Europe/Volgograd, Etc/GMT-4, Asia/Baku], +03:30=[Asia/Tehran, Iran], +03:00=[Asia/Aden, Asia/Qatar, Africa/Nairobi, Antarctica/Syowa, Asia/Riyadh, Africa/Juba, Europe/Moscow, Asia/Bahrain, Africa/Mogadishu, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Asia/Baghdad, Asia/Kuwait, Africa/Addis_Ababa, Asia/Istanbul, Africa/Djibouti, Europe/Kirov, Africa/Asmara, Africa/Asmera, Europe/Simferopol, Indian/Antananarivo, Africa/Kampala, Indian/Mayotte, W-SU, Turkey, Europe/Istanbul, Etc/GMT-3, Indian/Comoro, Europe/Minsk], +02:00=[Europe/Kiev, Asia/Hebron, Europe/Zaporozhye, Egypt, Asia/Nicosia, Africa/Lusaka, Europe/Kaliningrad, Africa/Gaborone, Africa/Maputo, Libya, Africa/Cairo, Africa/Windhoek, Europe/Mariehamn, Africa/Mbabane, Europe/Vilnius, Asia/Gaza, Europe/Chisinau, Asia/Famagusta, Africa/Maseru, Asia/Amman, Africa/Lubumbashi, Europe/Bucharest, Europe/Uzhgorod, Europe/Helsinki, Asia/Beirut, Asia/Tel_Aviv, Africa/Harare, Africa/Kigali, Europe/Sofia, Europe/Tallinn, Africa/Khartoum, Europe/Tiraspol, EET, Africa/Johannesburg, Europe/Nicosia, Asia/Damascus, Asia/Jerusalem, Africa/Bujumbura, Europe/Athens, Etc/GMT-2, Africa/Tripoli, Israel, Africa/Blantyre, Europe/Riga], +01:00=[Europe/Ljubljana, Africa/Libreville, Europe/Berlin, Africa/El_Aaiun, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Bratislava, Europe/San_Marino, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Malta, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Vienna, Africa/Douala, Europe/Busingen, Europe/Warsaw, CET, Etc/GMT-1, Africa/Malabo, Europe/Skopje, Europe/Podgorica, Europe/Paris, Africa/Ndjamena, Europe/Sarajevo, Europe/Tirane, Europe/Luxembourg, Africa/Bangui, Europe/Belgrade, MET, Arctic/Longyearbyen, Africa/Casablanca, Africa/Lagos, Europe/Rome, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Porto-Novo, Africa/Luanda, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Africa/Ceuta, Africa/Algiers, Europe/Zurich, Europe/Amsterdam, Poland, Europe/Vatican, Europe/Gibraltar, Africa/Kinshasa, Europe/Madrid, Europe/Vaduz, Africa/Niamey, Europe/Prague, Africa/Tunis, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Monaco], Z=[UTC, UCT, Portugal, Zulu, Iceland, Africa/Ouagadougou, Europe/Lisbon, Etc/Universal, Europe/London, Atlantic/Faeroe, Etc/GMT, Africa/Dakar, Atlantic/Canary, Universal, Africa/Lome, Africa/Freetown, GMT, Africa/Sao_Tome, Greenwich, Etc/GMT-0, Europe/Jersey, GB-Eire, Africa/Bissau, Europe/Belfast, Africa/Abidjan, Atlantic/Reykjavik, WET, Africa/Monrovia, Atlantic/St_Helena, Etc/Greenwich, Etc/GMT0, Africa/Bamako, Eire, Europe/Guernsey, Atlantic/Madeira, Africa/Timbuktu, GB, Africa/Accra, Africa/Conakry, Atlantic/Faroe, Etc/UTC, Etc/UCT, GMT0, Europe/Dublin, Etc/Zulu, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Africa/Nouakchott, Antarctica/Troll, Etc/GMT+0, Africa/Banjul, America/Danmarkshavn], -01:00=[America/Scoresbysund, Atlantic/Cape_Verde, Atlantic/Azores, Etc/GMT+1], -02:00=[Atlantic/South_Georgia, Brazil/DeNoronha, Etc/GMT+2, America/Noronha], -03:00=[America/Argentina/San_Juan, America/Cordoba, America/Sao_Paulo, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, America/Mendoza, America/Santarem, America/Asuncion, America/Belem, America/Montevideo, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Jujuy, America/Fortaleza, Brazil/East, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, America/Recife, America/Buenos_Aires, Antarctica/Palmer, America/Bahia, America/Argentina/Jujuy, America/Maceio, America/Argentina/Tucuman, America/Argentina/Cordoba, America/Paramaribo, America/Argentina/Mendoza, America/Punta_Arenas, America/Araguaina, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, America/Cayenne, Chile/Continental, Antarctica/Rothera, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, America/Catamarca, America/Godthab, America/Argentina/Salta, Etc/GMT+3, America/Miquelon, Atlantic/Stanley, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Rosario, America/Argentina/Catamarca, America/Santiago], -03:30=[America/St_Johns, Canada/Newfoundland], -04:00=[America/Caracas, America/Cuiaba, America/Dominica, America/Guadeloupe, America/Thule, America/St_Barthelemy, America/Curacao, America/La_Paz, America/Marigot, America/Moncton, America/Blanc-Sablon, Canada/Atlantic, America/Guyana, America/Martinique, America/Campo_Grande, Brazil/West, America/St_Thomas, Atlantic/Bermuda, America/Boa_Vista, America/Anguilla, America/St_Vincent, America/Aruba, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Grenada, America/Tortola, America/Goose_Bay, America/Virgin, America/Porto_Velho, SystemV/AST4ADT, America/Manaus, America/St_Lucia, America/Port_of_Spain, America/Montserrat, America/Barbados, America/Halifax, America/Kralendijk, America/Antigua, America/Santo_Domingo, America/Lower_Princes, America/St_Kitts, Etc/GMT+4, SystemV/AST4, America/Glace_Bay], -05:00=[America/Indianapolis, Canada/Eastern, America/Iqaluit, America/Port-au-Prince, America/Nipigon, America/Indiana/Vevay, America/Indiana/Winamac, America/Guayaquil, America/Fort_Wayne, Brazil/Acre, EST5EDT, America/Kentucky/Monticello, America/Coral_Harbour, US/East-Indiana, America/Cayman, America/Cancun, America/Panama, Pacific/Easter, America/Thunder_Bay, America/Grand_Turk, America/Lima, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Bogota, America/Pangnirtung, America/Havana, America/New_York, America/Indiana/Petersburg, America/Toronto, America/Porto_Acre, America/Indiana/Marengo, US/Michigan, Cuba, SystemV/EST5, SystemV/EST5EDT, America/Indiana/Vincennes, Chile/EasterIsland, America/Nassau, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, America/Jamaica, America/Eirunepe, America/Louisville, America/Atikokan, US/Eastern, America/Montreal, America/Rio_Branco, Jamaica, Etc/GMT+5, America/Detroit], -06:00=[America/Matamoros, America/Regina, America/El_Salvador, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, America/Costa_Rica, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/Guatemala, America/Winnipeg, America/Rankin_Inlet, America/Indiana/Knox, America/Belize, SystemV/CST6CDT, Mexico/General, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, CST6CDT, America/Swift_Current, America/Knox_IN, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Menominee, America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Managua, America/Resolute, US/Central, US/Indiana-Starke, America/Monterrey, America/Chicago, Pacific/Galapagos, America/Merida, America/Mexico_City, Canada/Central, America/Tegucigalpa, America/Rainy_River, Canada/Saskatchewan, Etc/GMT+6, SystemV/CST6], -07:00=[America/Inuvik, America/Yellowknife, US/Arizona, Mexico/BajaSur, Canada/Mountain, America/Cambridge_Bay, Navajo, America/Boise, America/Chihuahua, America/Ojinaga, SystemV/MST7MDT, MST7MDT, America/Creston, America/Phoenix, America/Dawson_Creek, America/Mazatlan, America/Shiprock, America/Denver, US/Mountain, America/Edmonton, America/Hermosillo, SystemV/MST7, Etc/GMT+7, America/Fort_Nelson], -08:00=[US/Pacific-New, Etc/GMT+8, America/Tijuana, SystemV/PST8, SystemV/PST8PDT, America/Santa_Isabel, Canada/Yukon, Canada/Pacific, America/Los_Angeles, America/Whitehorse, America/Ensenada, Pacific/Pitcairn, America/Dawson, PST8PDT, America/Vancouver, US/Pacific, Mexico/BajaNorte], -09:00=[America/Anchorage, Etc/GMT+9, America/Yakutat, America/Sitka, America/Metlakatla, America/Juneau, SystemV/YST9, SystemV/YST9YDT, US/Alaska, America/Nome, Pacific/Gambier], -09:30=[Pacific/Marquesas], -10:00=[America/Adak, US/Aleutian, Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Rarotonga, America/Atka, Etc/GMT+10, Pacific/Tahiti, US/Hawaii, Pacific/Johnston, SystemV/HST10], -11:00=[Pacific/Pago_Pago, Pacific/Midway, Pacific/Niue, Pacific/Samoa, Etc/GMT+11, US/Samoa], -12:00=[Etc/GMT+12]}

Let's look at your example of ten hours ahead of UTC (`+10:00`) we show:

> 10:00=[Pacific/Port_Moresby, Asia/Vladivostok, Pacific/Saipan, Asia/Ust-Nera, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Etc/GMT-10, Pacific/Truk, Australia/Lindeman, Pacific/Chuuk, Australia/Brisbane, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Yap, Australia/Queensland], +09:30=[Australia/North, Australia/Darwin]

Whoops! No `Australia/Sydney`. Look at eleven hours ahead of UTC instead, `+11:00`.

> +11:00=[Australia/Sydney, Pacific/Efate, Australia/LHI, Asia/Magadan, Pacific/Norfolk, Antarctica/Macquarie, Australia/Lord_Howe, Australia/Victoria, Etc/GMT-11, Pacific/Bougainville, Australia/Tasmania, Asia/Srednekolymsk, Australia/Currie, Pacific/Pohnpei, Australia/Melbourne, Pacific/Noumea, Australia/Hobart, Pacific/Ponape, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Australia/ACT, Australia/Canberra, Australia/NSW, Pacific/Kosrae, Asia/Sakhalin]

Bingo! At the moment of 2020-01-28T00:11:55.484156Z, `Australia/Sydney` is using an offset of eleven (11) hours ahead of UTC rather than ten (10). As discussed above, the offset varies over time per time zone. Thus, asking for a mapping of offset-to-zone makes no sense without the context of a moment.